# PHP - open a link, in a new window?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry if this is blatantly obvious, but I've Googled this and I seriously cannot find any PHP-only way to do it.

**Without** using an HTML or Javascript - pure PHP only (from a Controller file in a CodeIgniter site) - how can I open a browser window with a link I specify?

Is it possible?

Thanks!

**Edit:** it seems some people are misinterpreting what I mean, I apologise for not making it clear enough. I know with PHP you can set `header("Location: http://example.com")` to make the browser load a new window; I wanted to know if it was possible to send a header to say "open the `Location` in a new window".

**Edit 2:** to clarify what I want to do: the user can submit something to my site. Before clicking 'Submit', they can opt (via checkbox) to Tweet about it. If the checkbox is ticked, after everything's inserted into the database etc. a new window/tab loads with the URL `http://twitter.com/home?status=Hello%20World` or whatever the tweet will say. The user will have opted to do this so I'm not "doing something I shouldn't". I understand in hindsight though, that there probably is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It may be possible to encapsulate the html or javascript in such a way that what you're trying to do can be accomplished...

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about, do you? PHP is a virtual machine. Your browser parses markup (HTML) and at best will execute JavaScript. Now, if it's all not yet obvious to you, let me put it in simpler terms: PHP does not open links, browser opens links on behalf of the user operating it (hence the term User Agent). You can script the browser to open links, but I don't know a browser that will run PHP client-side, and if it would, there is no documented PHP API for "opening links". Either way, your question makes little to no sense. Type of site regardless.

Comment: @amn: What you've said is correct, but unecessarily harsh. Beginner PHPer's often are confused as to exactly what PHP is, so while an explanation is helpful and warranted, I don't think the general attitude of your comment is at all. Also, if you're going to be so nitpicky, you should get your facts straight: PHP is not a virtual machine - PHP *code* be run on a virtual machine, but it doesn't have to be (http://www.phpcompiler.org/).

Comment: @Jack: A twitter popup probably is not the best way to do this. Often they're blocked by popup blockers (especially if the popup is from another url, as that often means an ad), and they can be seen as annoying to users. Furthermore, it makes the site less useable on some mediums (eg. mobile). Why not include a tweet interface on the  thank-you page if they checked the box? That way there's still no javascript involved, and it keeps the site user friendly.

Comment: I apologize and hope you did not take it close to the heart, I am usually more cheerful :-) I chose to be harsh to initiate a reaction (which I did), I'll admit to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use a server-side language (PHP) to control client-side behavior (forcing a new browser window for a hyperlink).

Comment: @Jack: No. Think of what that would do - the user would click a link, and it would begin loading in the same window, and all of a sudden it would pop out into a new window. That would be Bad.

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: I don't believe there's such a header, not even a Web browser-specific one recognized by all browsers (browsers aren't the only HTTP clients).

Comment: Sending `<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('http://example.com');</script>` (with proper hypertext mime type) from server to the client will have browser attempt to open a new window with the url `http://example.com`, subject to popup-blocker policies etc. But again, I bet you are doing something you should not be doing, not for the good sake of your user(s) anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Codeigniter has a function that may do what you want

anchor_popup()

Nearly identical to the anchor() function except that it opens the URL in a new window. You can specify JavaScript window attributes in the third parameter to control how the window is opened. If the third parameter is not set it will simply open a new window with your own browser settings. Here is an example with attributes

In the URL helper

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using codeigniter you can take advantage of the URL helper library. Really this just forms html though.

Docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

You should probably autoload the url helper in config/autoload.php or just use

```
 $this->load->helper('url');


 echo anchor('http://your.link.com/whatever', 'title="My News"', array('target' => '_blank', 'class' => 'new_window'));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use pure html or codeigniter url helper as below......

1. open a link in **html** way..
2. using php Codeigniter, to open in **new Tab**
3. using php Codeigniter, to open in **new Window**

**$attributes** = {
'width' => '800', 'height' => '600', 'scrollbars' => 'yes', 'status' => 'yes', 'resizable'  => 'yes'
}

---

```
1. <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>

2. <?php echo anchor(prep_url('www.google.com'), 'Google', 'target="_blank"'); ?>

3. <?php echo anchor_popup(prep_url('www.google.com'), 'Google', '$attributes'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not PHP but HTML that will do the trick:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"some link here\" target=\"_blank\">";
?>
```

or simply outside php blocks:

```
<a href="some link here" target="_blank">
```

Comment: OP asked how **not** to use HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is echo, in php, the html to redirect, thats all I can think of, you have to use some other programming language.

Comment: I don't think *any* serverside language can accomplish this. There is really nothing you can send from the server that can cause a url to open in a new window without html/javascript, so changing your serverside language wouldn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in view, in the "anchor" that brings visitors to the controller function that does redirection.

Example:

In view you have:
  

  `anchor('news/external_link/'.$link['id'], 'target="_blank"');`

In "news" controller you have:
  


  `function external_link($id)

            {

               $url = $this->model->urls_model->get_url($id);`

```
      redirect(.$url); 
 }
```

In this example, "target blank" forces the url to open in a new tab. You can specify new window instead if you want. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post but I was recently just search this exact thing.

**Codeigniter** has a function very similar to `anchor()` called `anchor_popup()` which opens the target in a new window.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=anchor_popup#anchor_popup